# Error 500 por NullPointerException al ejecutar `cliente.jsp`

Tags: java, jsp, ejb

Este el archivo jsp que está dando el error.

**cliente.jsp**

```
<%@page import="pe.edu.sise.ejbbeans.ClienteFacadeLocal"%>
<%@page import="pe.edu.sise.entities.Cliente"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="pe.edu.sise.ejbbeans.ClienteFacade"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <h2>Clientes:</h2>
            <tr>
                <th>Id Cliente</th>
                <th>DNI</th>
                <th>Tipo Documento</th>
                <th>Nombres</th>
                <th>Apellidos</th>
                <th>Sexo</th>
                <th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
                <th>Total de Ingresos</th>
                <th>Dirección</th>

            </tr>
            <%
                Cliente j = new Cliente();
                ClienteFacadeLocal a = new ClienteFacade();
                List<Cliente> lista = a.findAll();
                for (Cliente c : lista) {
            %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= c.getNIdCliente()%></td>
                <td><%= c.getCDni()%></td>
                <td><%= c.getCTipoDoc()%></td>
                <td><%= c.getCNombres()%></td>
                <td><%= c.getCApellidos()%></td>
                <td><%= c.getCSexo()%></td>
                <td><%= c.getDFechaNacimiento()%></td>
                <td><%= c.getNTotalIngresos()%></td>
                <td><%= c.getCDireccion()%></td>

                <td><a href="ActualizarClientes.jsp?ID=<%= c.getNIdCliente()%>&&DNI=<%= c.getCDni()%>&&TIPO_DOCUMENTO=<%= c.getCTipoDoc()%>&&NOMBRES=<%= c.getCNombres()%>&&APELLIDOS=<%=c.getCApellidos()%>&&SEXO=<%=c.getCSexo()%>&&FECHA_NACIMIENTO=<%=c.getDFechaNacimiento()%>&&TOTAL_INGRESOS=<%=c.getNTotalIngresos()%>&&DIRECCION=<%=c.getCDireccion()%>">Actualizar</a></td>
                <td><a href="EliminarClientes.jsp?ID=<%= c.getNIdCliente()%>&&DNI=<%= c.getCDni()%>&&TIPO_DOCUMENTO=<%= c.getCTipoDoc()%>&&NOMBRES=<%= c.getCNombres()%>&&APELLIDOS=<%=c.getCApellidos()%>&&SEXO=<%=c.getCSexo()%>&&FECHA_NACIMIENTO=<%=c.getDFechaNacimiento()%>&&TOTAL_INGRESOS=<%=c.getNTotalIngresos()%>&&DIRECCION=<%=c.getCDireccion()%>">Eliminar</a></td>
            </tr>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Este es el detalle del error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException root
>   cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException note The full stack traces of the
>   exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server
>   Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.
>
> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1

¿Alguien sabe qué lo provoca?

---

CODIGO DE LA CLASE Cliente.java:

```
package pe.edu.sise.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "tbl_sise_cliente", catalog = "sise_bank", schema = "")
    @XmlRootElement
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByNIdCliente", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.nIdCliente = :nIdCliente"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByCDni", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.cDni = :cDni"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByCTipoDoc", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.cTipoDoc = :cTipoDoc"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByCNombres", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.cNombres = :cNombres"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByCApellidos", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.cApellidos = :cApellidos"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByCSexo", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.cSexo = :cSexo"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByDFechaNacimiento", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.dFechaNacimiento = :dFechaNacimiento"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByNTotalIngresos", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.nTotalIngresos = :nTotalIngresos"),


        @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByCDireccion", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.cDireccion = :cDireccion")})
        public class Cliente implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "N_ID_CLIENTE")
        private Integer nIdCliente;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
        @Column(name = "C_DNI")
        private String cDni;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "C_TIPO_DOC")
        private Character cTipoDoc;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
        @Column(name = "C_NOMBRES")
        private String cNombres;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
        @Column(name = "C_APELLIDOS")
        private String cApellidos;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "C_SEXO")
        private Character cSexo;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "D_FECHA_NACIMIENTO")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date dFechaNacimiento;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "N_TOTAL_INGRESOS")
        private double nTotalIngresos;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 80)
        @Column(name = "C_DIRECCION")
        private String cDireccion;

        public Cliente() {
        }

        public Cliente(Integer nIdCliente) {
            this.nIdCliente = nIdCliente;
        }

        public Cliente(Integer nIdCliente, String cDni, Character cTipoDoc, String cNombres, String cApellidos, Character cSexo, Date dFechaNacimiento, double nTotalIngresos, String cDireccion) {
            this.nIdCliente = nIdCliente;
            this.cDni = cDni;
            this.cTipoDoc = cTipoDoc;
            this.cNombres = cNombres;
            this.cApellidos = cApellidos;
            this.cSexo = cSexo;
            this.dFechaNacimiento = dFechaNacimiento;
            this.nTotalIngresos = nTotalIngresos;
            this.cDireccion = cDireccion;
        }

        public Integer getNIdCliente() {
            return nIdCliente;
        }

        public void setNIdCliente(Integer nIdCliente) {
            this.nIdCliente = nIdCliente;
        }

        public String getCDni() {
            return cDni;
        }

        public void setCDni(String cDni) {
            this.cDni = cDni;
        }

        public Character getCTipoDoc() {
            return cTipoDoc;
        }

        public void setCTipoDoc(Character cTipoDoc) {
            this.cTipoDoc = cTipoDoc;
        }

        public String getCNombres() {
            return cNombres;
        }

        public void setCNombres(String cNombres) {
            this.cNombres = cNombres;
        }

        public String getCApellidos() {
            return cApellidos;
        }

        public void setCApellidos(String cApellidos) {
            this.cApellidos = cApellidos;
        }

        public Character getCSexo() {
            return cSexo;
        }

        public void setCSexo(Character cSexo) {
            this.cSexo = cSexo;
        }

        public Date getDFechaNacimiento() {
            return dFechaNacimiento;
        }

        public void setDFechaNacimiento(Date dFechaNacimiento) {
            this.dFechaNacimiento = dFechaNacimiento;
        }

        public double getNTotalIngresos() {
            return nTotalIngresos;
        }

        public void setNTotalIngresos(double nTotalIngresos) {
            this.nTotalIngresos = nTotalIngresos;
        }

        public String getCDireccion() {
            return cDireccion;
        }

        public void setCDireccion(String cDireccion) {
            this.cDireccion = cDireccion;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 0;
            hash += (nIdCliente != null ? nIdCliente.hashCode() : 0);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object object) {
            // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
            if (!(object instanceof Cliente)) {
                return false;
            }
            Cliente other = (Cliente) object;
            if ((this.nIdCliente == null && other.nIdCliente != null) || (this.nIdCliente != null && !this.nIdCliente.equals(other.nIdCliente))) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "pe.edu.sise.entities.Cliente[ nIdCliente=" + nIdCliente + " ]";
        }

    }
```

---

CODIGO DE AbstractFacade.java:

```
package pe.edu.sise.ejbbeans;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;


public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

}
```

---

CODIGO DE ClienteFacade.java:

```
package pe.edu.sise.ejbbeans;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import pe.edu.sise.entities.Cliente;


@Stateless
public class ClienteFacade extends AbstractFacade<Cliente> implements ClienteFacadeLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "EJB_SiseBank2PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public ClienteFacade() {
        super(Cliente.class);
    }

    public void listarClienteSQLNativo(){
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_sise_cliente");
        List l = q.getResultList();

    }

    public void insertarClienteSQLNativo(){
        em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO tbl_sise_cliente(N_ID_CLIENTE,C_DNI,C_TIPO_DOC,C_NOMBRES,C_APELLIDOS,C_SEXO,D_FECHA_NACIMIENTO,N_TOTAL_INGRESOS,C_DIRECCION)"
                + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_sise_cliente");
        List l = q.getResultList();

    }

    public void actualizarClienteSQLNativo(){
        em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE tbl_sise_cliente SET C_DNI=?,C_TIPO_DOC=?,C_NOMBRES=?,C_APELLIDOS=?,C_SEXO=?,D_FECHA_NACIMIENTO=?,N_TOTAL_INGRESOS=?,C_DIRECCION=? WHERE N_ID_CLIENTE=?");
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_sise_cliente");
        List l = q.getResultList();

    }

    public void eliminarClienteSQLNativo(){
        em.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM tbl_sise_cliente WHERE N_ID_CLIENTE=?");
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_sise_cliente");
        List l = q.getResultList();
    }

}
```

---

CODIGO DE ClienteFacadeLocal.java:

```
package pe.edu.sise.ejbbeans;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Local;
import pe.edu.sise.entities.Cliente;


@Local
public interface ClienteFacadeLocal {

    void create(Cliente cliente);

    void edit(Cliente cliente);

    void remove(Cliente cliente);

    Cliente find(Object id);

    List<Cliente> findAll();

    List<Cliente> findRange(int[] range);

    int count();

}
```

---

CODIGO del archivo "server.log" del GLASSFISH 4.1:

```
[2016-09-07T03:45:40.775-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=92 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1473237940775] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pe.edu.sise.ejbbeans.AbstractFacade.findAll(AbstractFacade.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.cuenta_jsp._jspService(cuenta_jsp.java:76)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

---

BASE DE DATOS DE MySQL:

```
-- 
-- Base de datos: `sise_bank`
-- 

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `tbl_sise_cliente`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `tbl_sise_cliente` (
  `N_ID_CLIENTE` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `C_DNI` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `C_TIPO_DOC` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `C_NOMBRES` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `C_APELLIDOS` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `C_SEXO` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `D_FECHA_NACIMIENTO` date NOT NULL,
  `N_TOTAL_INGRESOS` double(19,2) NOT NULL,
  `C_DIRECCION` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`N_ID_CLIENTE`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

-- 
-- Volcar la base de datos para la tabla `tbl_sise_cliente`
-- 

INSERT INTO `tbl_sise_cliente` (`N_ID_CLIENTE`, `C_DNI`, `C_TIPO_DOC`, `C_NOMBRES`, `C_APELLIDOS`, `C_SEXO`, `D_FECHA_NACIMIENTO`, `N_TOTAL_INGRESOS`, `C_DIRECCION`) VALUES (1, '10599019', '1', 'Percy Alejandro', 'Arellano Samamé', 'M', '1976-12-13', 890.26, 'Los Portales 3ra. etapa ATE-VITARTE');
INSERT INTO `tbl_sise_cliente` (`N_ID_CLIENTE`, `C_DNI`, `C_TIPO_DOC`, `C_NOMBRES`, `C_APELLIDOS`, `C_SEXO`, `D_FECHA_NACIMIENTO`, `N_TOTAL_INGRESOS`, `C_DIRECCION`) VALUES (2, '10606172', '1', 'Oscar Roberto', 'Arellano Samamé', 'M', '1977-03-13', 830.52, 'Los Portales 3ra. etapa ATE-VITARTE');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `tbl_sise_cuenta`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `tbl_sise_cuenta` (
  `N_ID_CUENTA` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `N_ID_CLIENTE` int(11) default NULL,
  `C_NUM_CUENTA` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `N_MONTO` double(19,2) default NULL,
  `C_TIPO_CUENTA` char(1) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`N_ID_CUENTA`),
  KEY `FK_N_ID_CLIENTE` (`N_ID_CLIENTE`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Tal y cómo te dice el error: ` java.lang.NullPointerException` tiene pinta a problema en el codebheind. ¿En los logs del glassFish qué te aparece? (además, te invito a visitar el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) de la página)

Comment: Ahi en la carpeta LOG del glassfish 4.1 hay sólo un archivo server.log; ¿te paso todo lo que dice ahí para que me lo descifres, qué opinas?

Comment: Si puedes editar tu pregunta añadiendo sólo las partes **relevantes** mejor :)

Comment: Bueno, yo lo que quiero es que este JSP cuando lo ejecute, me muestre o me liste los registros de la BD de MySQL, pero no lo hace, sale el error del GlassFish que he publicado... ¿a qué se debe?... Este JSP está incluido en un proyecto web acoplado a un proyecto EJB hecho con la persistencia de ENTIDADES y FACADES

Comment: Podrías copiar dentro de tu pregunta el código de las clases **Cliente** (constructor) y **ClienteFacade** (constructor y findAll).

Comment: alguno de los acceso al  los atributos del objeto es null, pega el log de servidor.

Comment: Necesito respuestas y soluciones urgente por favor.... :( :(

Comment: El stacktrace indica claramente dónde se lanza el NPE: `at pe.edu.sise.ejbbeans.AbstractFacade.findAll(AbstractFacade.java:42)`. Por favor muéstranos el código relevante de la clase `AbstractFacade`, el método `findAll` que está en la línea 42 de dicha clase. Supongo que hay un elemento que no ha sido inicializado.

Comment: Este es el método findAll() en la línea 42:                                                                                        `public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }`

Comment: Este método findAll() en la línea 42 es del archivo AbstractFacade.java  del archivo EJB, ahí se lanzó el NPE = Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: Hola a todos...¿y qué fue?

Answer (score 1):

Pues indudablemente, estas llamando al metodo findAll de la interface clienteFacadeLocal, pero por el extends que tienes no t pide implementar el metodo, crea un metodo como el siguiente:

```
@override   ///este es el metodo de local facade que vas a implementar
    List<Cliente> findAll(){
return findAll();/// este es el metodo de AbstractFacade

}
```

Inténtalo y me comentas.